# JavaScript - referencing arguments from within a function

Tags: javascript, function, functional-programming

Recently i found myself attaching function arguments to a variable inside the function scope so that i was not referencing the argument every time it was used.

Is there any benefit to this practice?

For example:

```
function populateResultCount(count){
    var count = count;
    return $('.resultCounter').text(count);     
};
```

Could easily be re-written like so:

```
function populateResultCount(count){
    return $('.resultCounter').text(count);     
};
```

And would still function correctly.

Comment: A JavaScript function stores values of arguments and values of local variables in the same place (the `Variables` object - at least that's how it was called back in ES3), so there is not difference between retrieving the value of an argument vs retrieving the value of a local variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not using the argument that's passed in, there is no difference. In your first example, you can potentially confuse future maintainers because of `var count = count`, i.e., you're declaring a variable that has the same name as the argument, and that isn't a best practise.

So, if you can, use your second form. Its intent is clearer and there is no room for confusion.

Answer (score 3):

There's no functional difference between the two.  Go with the simpler version.

Answer (score 1):

I can see no benefit to this unless you are manipulating the data somehow. Your variable without the additional assingment can still not be accessed outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

All the other answers are correct: There's no reason to "re-assign" a passed argument inside the function.

The only thing I can think of, where you'd mess with reassigning arguments, is if you have optional arguments/default values

```
function xyz(optionalArgument) {
    optionalArgument = optionalArgument || "no argument given";
    ...
}
```

But in that case, it'd be better to write it as

```
function xyz( /* optionalArgument */ ) {
    var optionalArgument = arguments[0] || "no argument given";
    ...
}
```

Note that the `||` trick will give you the right-hand side's value, if the left-hand side is a falsy value. I.e. if you're ok with the optional argument being something that's falsy (like explicitly passing `null`, `0`, etc), you'd have to do something like `var arg = typeof arguments[x] === 'undefined' ? defaultValue : arguments[x];`

Answer (score 1):

```
function Test (count) {
    this.increment = function() {
        count++;
    }

    this.getCount = function() {
        return count;
    }
}

var test = new Test(10);


<button onclick="test.increment(); alert(test.getCount());">Increment</button>
```

You can do something like that even with the argument. So I think they are same.